# Allow the end user to schedule task with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Spring Boot and I want to allow the end user to schedule task as he wants.

I have a Spring Boot REST backend with a Angular frontend. The user should be able to schedule (with a crontab style syntax) a task (i.e. a class' method backend side), and choose some arguments.

The user should alse be able to view, edit, delete scheduled task from the front end

I know I can use @Scheduled annotation, but I don't see how the end user can schedule task with it. I also take a look at Quartz, but I don't see how to set the user's argument in my method call.

Should I use Spring Batch?

Comment: should the user configure the cron tab syntax or just start a job?

Comment: The user should configure the cron tab syntax

Comment: I think you have to be more specific how the things should work. How the user should schedule tasks? Using a request, any frontend, or direct access to a property file and so on? At the end there are some solutions to get the stuff work. For example store the cron tab in the DB and configure the jobs in you app.

Comment: The users should configure theirs tasks using an Angular frontend. They should be able to add, edit, remove a task within the frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To schedule job programatically, you have the following options:

- For simple cases you can have a look at `ScheduledExecutorService`, which can schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically. It's in package `java.util.concurrent` and easy to use.
- To schedule Crontab job dynamically, you can use quartz and [here's official examples](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example3), basically what you'll do is:

  - Create instance `Scheduler`, which can be defined as a java bean and `autowire` by Spring, example code:
  - Create `JobDetail`
  - Create `CronTrigger`
  - Schedule the `job` with `cron`

Official example code(scheduled to run every 20 seconds):

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();

JobDetail job = newJob(SimpleJob.class)
.withIdentity("job1", "group1")
.build();

CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
.withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
.withSchedule(cronSchedule("0/20 * * * * ?"))
.build();

sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```